# In java, why can I only import abstract classes?

Tags: java

In my Java I have a class import:

```java
import cc.hyperium.mods.HyperiumModIntegration;
```

however, it fails to import with error `Cannot resolve symbol 'HyperiumModIntegration'`.

The class I'm importing looks like this:

```java
package cc.hyperium.mods;
public class HyperiumModIntegration {
    public HyperiumModIntegration() {
    }
}
```

Weirdly, if I make the class abstract, it imports just fine.

IntelliJ will show the class in code completion, however.

[image: Code Completion]

Comment: Is that class in the same project or in a dependency? `abstract` or not should have no effect on being able to import a class. Is the class in this question really the **full** class? Is it possible that the class doesn't compile as a non-abstract class (because it's missing methods) and that causes the import problem?

Comment: That is the full class, and yes its in the same project

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it and can't quite imagine what could cause the class to be not found if it was non-abstract. How do you build the project? Only within the IDE or using a proper build system (Maven, Gradle, Ant, ...) as well?

Comment: I just build with IntelliJ, so pretty sure it uses Ant https://i.imgur.com/Py1rM06.png

Comment: `.../src/cc/hyperium/mods/HyperiumModIntegration.java`

Comment: I fear this issue is caused by something else you did. This looks nothing like [`HyperiumModIntegration`](https://github.com/HyperiumClient/Hyperium/blob/master/src/main/java/cc/hyperium/mods/HyperiumModIntegration.java). Could you explain what you are trying to do on the large scale? It might by an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I'm attempting to repurpose the Hyperium injection / mixin code for a client and removed the mods as i didnt want them

Comment: i'll try get gradle working and see if that fixes it

Comment: Maybe it helps if you use `File`>`Invalidate Caches and Restart`. IntelliJ sometimes is a bit weird with things like moving classes.

Comment: Oh yeah good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidating caches and restarting in IntelliJ fixed it.

*(Note to self: stop using EAP.)*

Comment: IDEA EAPs are really only worth it if you are actively using a feature (or bugfix) that they bring. I would avoid using them by default, as they *will* have the occasional bug (that's just the cost of heavy development).